# How to represent a microphone using a voltage dependent current source in LTspice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, microphone

I am using the following schematic and I'm trying to simulate it in LTspice but I am not sure how to represent the microphone. My instructor said I should use a voltage dependent current source but I don't know how to hook it up or simulate the circuit? If you want more information on the circuit go to https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa290/sboa290.pdf?ts=1606276354037.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No need for VCCS, a simple current source will do. Though even a voltage source will be fine.

Comment: Presumably you want to module your VCCS with some signal and observe the output ? Is this correct ? Then you can model the mic with the VCCS and some high impedance in parallel with its two terminals. Then hook up your generator/modulator to the VCCS voltage port to modulate the signal with whatever waveform you require. A more accurate model may include some capacitance, inductance etc depending on how accurate you need to model the microphone ...

Comment: I suggest that you look up how a typical Electret mic. is constructed. The electret is like a small capacitor with an electrical charge fixed onto the plates. There is also a JFET inside the mic. to convert the voltage changes across the small capacitor into a usable signal. The output of the mic. is actually the drain of the JFET so a VCCS makes sense as the small signal equivalent of a JFET is a VCCS.